# How do I use Pandas groupby to group by a nameless index?

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have a large data frame which is indexed by time steps. I am trying to make a calculation iterated across all columns of each time step, but the index is not named by a string, so I do not know how to specify the group.

Comment: `df.groupby(level=0)` or whatever your index level is that you want to group on

Answer (score 0):

assume the dataframe has only one level of index:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,0,0,0], 'col2': [0,0,1,0]}, index=[0,0,1,1])
```

```py
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,0,0,0], 'col2': [0,0,1,0]}, index=[0,0,1,1])

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
   col1  col2
0     1     0
0     0     0
1     0     1
1     0     0
```

[the document of "Splitting an object into groups"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#splitting-an-object-into-groups)
states:

> The mapping can be specified many different ways:
>
> - A Python function, to be called on each of the axis labels.
> - A list or NumPy array of the same length as the selected axis.
> - **A dict or Series, providing a label -> group name mapping.**
> - For DataFrame objects, a string indicating either a column name or an index level name to be used to group.
> - `df.groupby('A')` is just syntactic sugar for `df.groupby(df['A'])`.
> - A list of any of the above things.

what we need to focus is "a label -> group name", "label" means the name of a value in index, we just pass the index of the dataframe itself as the map, and then the
dataframe wiil group by the index.

so just use `df.groupby(df.index)`, examples below:

```py
In [6]: df.groupby(df.index).sum()
Out[6]: 
   col1  col2
0     1     0
1     0     1

In [7]: df.groupby(df.index).max()
Out[7]: 
   col1  col2
0     1     0
1     0     1

In [8]: df.groupby(df.index).min()
Out[8]: 
   col1  col2
0     0     0
1     0     0
```